# Прототипы в JavaScript

Tags: javascript, prototype

Учу прототипы, посмотрел этот пример у Кантора в книге. зачем в скобках `this` прописан?

```
String.prototype.repeat = function(times) {
    return new Array(times + 1).join(this);
};
console.log('text'.repeat(2));
```

Что значит `join(this)`?

Comment: `this` в данном случае равен `'text'`, потому что метод `repeat` вызван на этой строке.

Comment: @smellyshovel то есть по сути `this` всегда должен быть равен чему-то?

Comment: Если strict mode (`"use strict"` в начале файла/функции) не включен, то да (в общем случае, а при вызове `repeat` в качестве метода - всегда равен тому, на чем вызван).

Comment: @smellyshovel ну вот у меня он всегда включен, тогда всегда в голове держать, что `this` должен быть чему-то равен

Comment: Да нет, я не об этом. Просто примите себе за правило, что если вы обычную (не стрелочную) функцию вызываете как `что-то.myFunc()`, то в `myFunc` `this` будет указывать на это `что-то`. А если эту функцию вы вызовите просто как `myFunc()`, то тут уже зависит от strict mode.

Comment: @smellyshovel, окей, спасибо. понял. последний вопрос, вытекающий из вашего ответа, а разве стрелочные функции не то же самое что и обычные, просто в укороченной записи?

Comment: Нет. Отличий довольно много. Поищите, здесь есть развернутый ответ.